# Monitor WordPress Downloads?

Tags: wordpress

I am running a website on WordPress, where i share design PSDs. I am getting high traffic from google and other sites. I want to monitor downloads going from my website. I am uploading the files with FTP and adding links in the post.

I have tried many WordPress plugins but none of them was working as i want. Can any one please tell me how i can monitor the download hits going from my website.

I have tried these plugins

- Download Monitor
- Simple Download Monitor
- WordPress Download Manager
- CM Download Manager

Can anyone tell me any thing for monitoring my downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Analytics maybe?](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/how-to-track-downloads-in-google-analytics/) You do have to edit your theme files to get this working though. Otherwise the plugins you listed are the best known I guess. At least the ones I've seen in the last years.

Also I thought [Yoast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) tracks outbound and downloads as well, might wanna check that.

Comment: Thanks. I will try Yoast for this but still find some thing more close.

Comment: just got a tweet about this, might be helpful to 'ya http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-digital-downloads/

Comment: There might be a paid solution at CodeCanyon, WP section. Mostly $5 - $15 plugins there.

Comment: Yeah i have installed a paid app but it simply waste of money. My users are complaining that the file is not downloadable and showing 404 page.